# Pandas: Sort Dataframe is Column Value Exists in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database which has two columns with unique numbers. This is my reference dataframe (df_reference). In another dataframe (df_data) I want to get the rows of this dataframe of which a column values exist in this reference dataframe. I tried stuff like:

```
df_new = df_data[df_data['ID'].isin(df_reference)]
```

However, like this I can't get any results. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are passing the whole dataframe in .isin() method.
Try:

```
df_new = df_data[df_data['ID'].isin(df_reference['ID'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `ID` column to the index of the `df_data` data frame. Then you could do

```
matching_index = df_reference['ID']
df_new = df_data.loc[matching_index, :]
```

This should solve the issue.